# Run Python Script on CentOS as a Background Task

Tags: python, ssh, centos, telethon

I rented a CentOS 7 Server for my python scripts. I created a python script that connects my telegram account and forwards messages to targets. I used telethon to do this.
When I connect to server via ssh, I can run script. When I logged out, my script is not working.

I used nohup and & but still can't run script until reboot or shutdown. After logout with nohup, my script working for a while but shutting down again.

What are the points that I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background processes are related to the user session, once you disconnect that session ends and such processes are terminated. To solve your problem you need to create a service which runs independently. In particular you need to first create a service configuration file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Python program
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=centos
ExecStart=<command to start your program>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where  is the command you use to execute your program.

This file needs to be saved in /etc/systemd/system/<my_service>.service where <my_service> is a name of your choice.

To make the program started when system reboot:

```
sudo systemctl enable <my_service>.service
```

To start manually the program:

```
sudo systemctl start <my_service>.service
```

This should fix your issue

Comment: In addition to that, don't forget to use a previously logged-in session. Otherwise, systemd will run the process which will attempt to prompt for user input ("enter the received Telegram code") which will likely fail. So you're encouraged to use an absolute session file path to make sure this doesn't happen (and check the file permissions).

Comment: I got it first of all, I have to login my telegram. I did it and my script created session files. now i can create my service.

Comment: I got start repeated too quickly error and my service is not work. How can i fix this?